# Thymeleaf-test test thtest files with objects in context created by java JUnit

Tags: java, junit, thymeleaf

I am generating a mail template as plain text/html and try to test it with thymeleaf-test.

I currently struggle with generating the context for the templates from the surrounding java JUnit code.

```
 @Test
 void testTheymeleaf() {
    TestExecutor executor = new TestExecutor();
    executor.execute("classpath:mail/testResults.thtest");
    Assertions.assertTrue(executor.isAllOK());
 }
```

**How do I bring the context for processing the template to the executor?**

I know I can do it from within the thtest-file but that is not a viable solution as the context contains multiple aggregated objects. (and additionally, the needed data in the context is already present from other tests and can be coppied).

Comment: I also posted/requested this on https://github.com/thymeleaf/thymeleaf-testing/issues/30

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution like so:

```
public class WebProcessingContextBuilderWithJavaVariables extends WebProcessingContextBuilder {

    private final Map<String, Object> vars;

    public WebProcessingContextBuilderWithJavaVariables(Map<String, Object> variables) {
        vars = variables;
    }

    @Override
    protected void doAdditionalVariableProcessing(
            final ITest test,
            final HttpServletRequest request, final HttpServletResponse response, final ServletContext servletContext,
            final Locale locale, final Map<String, Object> variables) {

        variables.putAll(vars);
    }
}
```

This class is used in the tests to set a custom executor which gets the variables for the context.

```
@Test
void someTest() {
    HashMap<String, Object> vars = new HashMap<>();
    vars.put("key", validations);
    executor.setProcessingContextBuilder(new WebProcessingContextBuilderWithJavaVariables(vars));
    executor.execute("classpath:template.thtest");

    Assertions.assertTrue(executor.isAllOK());
}
```